# Are the final position coordinates (X, Y) independent in a simple 2D random walk?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, random-walk

The situation I am trying to ask about is the following:

Starting at the origin, a single step is taken at random either up, down, left, or right. If n steps are taken, then the final position after these n movements is (X, Y). Are X and Y independent?

Comment: Hint: What happens if you know almost all steps were taken parallel to the $x$-axis?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. However, it turns out that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $\Pr[ X = 0 \mid Y = n] = 1$, for instance.